# Do array instance and Array.prototype share a single length property?

Tags: javascript

According to the ECMAScript spec, Array instances, which are exotic objects, inherit properties from the Array prototype object ([ref](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-properties-of-array-instances)). One of such properties is a well-known `length`. Changing it directly on an instance may result in removing certain index-keyed properties ([ref](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-properties-of-array-instances-length)).

On the other hand, as it is said [elsewhere](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots) with respect to ordinary objects, prototype's data properties are not inherited for the purposes of set access. It means an attempt to set a property on a instance that has not such a key among its *own* properties keys causes creating a new own property with this key whether a prototype knows this key or not.

Due to I can't find a similar notion but conernced with Array exotic objects, I wonder what should happen when we doing something like this:

```
let arr = [0, 1, 2];
arr.length = 1;
```

Was an own property defned on the instance with the prototype's one keeping untouched or are we tinkering with the same `length` here (that of the prototype's)?

Comment: The specification you link to defines `.length` under *Properties of Array Instances*. I.e., it doesn't come from the prototype.

Comment: If you were changing the property `length` property, then *every single array* would now have `length` of one. Moreover, *all arrays everywhere at all times* would only be able to have the same length if they all shared it through the prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, array instances do not share their `length` property with `Array.prototype`. These are distinct properties.

First of all, the specification indicates that `Array.prototype` is itself an Array -- which is why it has a `length` property. See [Properties of the Array Prototype Object](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-properties-of-the-array-prototype-object):

> - is an Array exotic object and has the internal methods specified for such objects.
> - has a **"length"** property whose initial value is **+0**

Secondly, when arrays a constructed, like with the [`Array`](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-array) function, the steps in [`ArrayCreate`](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-arraycreate) are executed:

> #### ArrayCreate ( *length* [ , *proto* ] ):
>
> [...]
> 6. Perform ! OrdinaryDefineOwnProperty(*A*, **"length"**, PropertyDescriptor { [[Value]]: (*length*), [[Writable]]: **true**, [[Enumerable]]: **false**, [[Configurable]]: **false** }).

This leaves no doubt that every constructed array has its own `length` property.

As an illustration, we can modify `Array.prototype.length` from its default value of 0 to another value, and then see that this does not influence the value of `length` of an instance that is created later:

```js
console.log(Array.prototype.length); // 0
Array.prototype.length = 1;
console.log(Array.prototype.length); // 1
console.log(Array().length); // 0
```